# Checking int cast from null

Tags: java, casting, null

I wrote some code like this:

```
Map<String, Object> map;
-- some code --
int result = (int) map.get("some_integer");
```

If there is no value with a key named `some_integer`, then `map.get("some_integer")` will return `null`. Then, it is cast as `int`, which can't be `null`.

My questions are:

1. What will `(int) map.get("some_integer")` return?
2. How can I check `null` with `result`?

Comment: why can't u test yourself ? you have IDE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try and cast `null` to an `int`, you will get a `NullPointerException`.

If you want to null-check it, you can use an `Integer` or `Object` variable.

```
Integer r = (Integer) map.get("some_integer");
if (r==null) {
   // whatever you want to do in this case
} else {
   int result = r;
   // whatever you want to do with the result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a default:

```
Map map = new HashMap<String, Object> ();
map.put ("seven", new Integer(7));
Object o = map.getOrDefault ("seven", new Integer (0));
```